# Can I use std::optional for error handling?

Tags: c++, stl, c++17

With C++17 we got `std::optional` which is a useful wrapper for expressing nullable types.

Can I use it for error handling? It's quite appealing to do so:

```
optional<int> Compute()
{
  //... compute something valid...
  return std::nullopt; // error!
}
```

Would it be a good choice? Isn't it the same are returning a null pointer?

The problem, that people reports, is that you lose a message what happened in the case of an error. So returning some status code might be better.

other alternatives:

- `std::variant<Value, errorCode>`
- `std::pair<Value, errorCode`
- return error code and have a value as an output parameter
- throw an exception

Comment: [The examples on cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional) are doing exactly that.

Comment: I've updated the question: don't we lose the info about "what happened" that way? error code can provide more info. Probably it depends on the complexity of the function.

Comment: Very much opinion based. I would like to ask fellow StackOverflowers to resist the urge and **NOT** provide an answer.

Comment: I think this is partially opinion-based, but not primarily so. The distinction between error-handling and regular flow control is an important aspect of programming, even though a computer couldn't care less. After all "error" and "not error" are human interpretations based on human assumptions and expectations that are in and of themselves opinion-based, but we don't disallow that topic either.

Comment: You may find this library of interest. `std::optional` does not carry information about causes of error, so its usefulness in error handling is limited.
https://ned14.github.io/outcome/

Answer (score 2):

I think `std::optional` is a great replacement for error handling code like that:

```
int GetAvailablePositiveNumber()
{
    if (condition)
        return 1;
    if (condition2);
        return 2;
    return -1;
}

int result = GetAvailablePositiveNumber();
if (result == -1)
{
    // We have no available positive numbers - handle error;
}
```

You will never need to use -1 ever again.

Also about the other alternatives you have mentioned, my answer is: the right tool for the right job. They have their own uses. Just pick the best tool on a case-by-case basis.

Comment: Probably depends if your function has only one way to return "no value". If you have more options (system failure, out of memory, network failure, etc, etc...) then it's better to pass more error information to the caller

Comment: Why not throw an exception in this case? I'm aware this is not a strict black/white topic, but where do you draw the line?

Comment: @fen Of course!!!!

Comment: @fen Exactly. `std::optional` is not expressive enough for general purpose error handling, as the only information you get is "something went wrong."

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt If your coding standard prescribes: "DO NOT EVER USE EXCEPTIONS!"

Comment: so std::optional can add more confusion as you have one more way to express that something went wrong

Comment: Okay, that may be the case, but that means "DO NOT USE C++" in fact.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt Rather, "Do not use the dialect of C++ that I'm used to." Yes, it's strongly recommended to use exceptions even by Bjarne Stroustrup and the like. However, there are people legitimately using C++ who turn off exceptions (e.g. game programming). It's exclusive to say that they aren't using C++, when they clearly are

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt In my industry I have yet to see a single exception used by Sony or Nintendo but Microsoft uses them generously. Can you guess which system behaves the worst?

Comment: That's not an argument nor is it an explanation, @Zingam. Even if your observation was right, it might be mere coincidence. Correlation does not imply causation.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt Unlike idiomatic Python I have never heard the phrase "idiomatic C++". I think C++ is a language that you don't have to pay for what you don't need to use, which is the best part of it.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt Here is the JSF coding standard conceived by Bjarne Stroustrup himself: http://www.stroustrup.com/JSF-AV-rules.pdf AV Rule 208 states:
`C++ exceptions shall not be used (i.e. throw, catch and try shall not be used.)` I am not against exceptions I just say that you are not obliged to use them just because you can.

Comment: And here is the reason why somebody might not want to use exceptions: https://qph.ec.quoracdn.net/main-qimg-f21ea317da1c0adfeda0a8492ad4a89e.webp

Comment: "Rationale: Tool support is not adequate at this time." ... sigh. Also, that table you provided is making claims/interpretations while omitting observable facts (like e.g. how that was measured).

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt This guide also advocates for exceptions and gives further context on the tooling support issue: https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/exceptions#why-exceptions

Answer (score 1):

In general I'd say it's a good choice. Returning `optional` is an expressive way to indicate that "return value can be present or not'.

Regarding alternatives you provided - of course they are suitable options, but you need return code only if you need to distinguish between reasons *why* there is no return value.
And last 2 options (output parameter and exception) requires quite an overhead on the function call side.

So I'd choose `std::optional` as a default way to do this, and consider other options only if there are specific reason to (e.g. no `std::optional` available, conventions, etc)

Comment: Exceptions don't require any overhead on the function call side, neither in terms of code nor in terms of execution time. This is only if you wrap every single call in a try-catch-clause instead of letting any exception propagate up the stack.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt Good point, in case of critical error - it's more natural to let exception propagate up. But in case of such types of failure which are expected from business-logic point of view - you may want to keep track of failures right in place, maybe to adjust the flow. So it's two completely different scenarios, and I was rather thinking of second one.

Comment: Tnanks for clarifying that, that way it makes sense!

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt Exceptions do have overhead, and a lot of it, when they get thrown.  This overhead happens on the call side even if you don't catch it (think about destructors/stack unwinding).  https://mortoray.com/2013/09/12/the-true-cost-of-zero-cost-exceptions/

Comment: Destructors and stack unwinding happen, regardless of whether a function throws or returns. Anyhow, throwing exceptions is indeed not cheap. However, and that was my main point, if they are only used in exceptional cases, that shouldn't impact performance. If you compare just the non-error performance, exceptions even excel in runtime performance, since there is simply less code to execute.

Answer (score -1):

Using optional, you can extend all possible values that a type can have by one additional signal value which represents the absence of any value. This is similar to floating point NaN.

No, don't use it for error handling. If you have an error, throw an exception by default. Note that in C, you would often return null and set errno, but C doesn't have any other means to signal errors. Also note that the distinction between error and "special case" is a matter of taste and context, so don't take this as a definitive answer but apply own judgement.

Yes, it is similar to returning a null pointer. If something is not always there, then this optional type is the right thing. The absence of this thing is not an error though, so it is not signalled using exceptions.

Examples:

- malloc() if no memory is available, it can't return anything so it restricts the possible pointer values by one which is the null pointer. Using an optional<void*>, you could use the full address range.
- However, failure to allocate memory is usually treated as error, hence `new` throws.
- When checking into a hotel, a reservation could be an optional. It's not an error if you don't have one, but it requires a few different steps if you don't.
- The intersection between two lines is also an optional value, because it may or may not exist. Other mathematical functions that don't always have solutions can also be modeled that way.
- Caches are conveniently modeled using optionals, too.

Comment: `trow an exception by default`. Disagree wholeheartedly.

Comment: Do you just disagree or do you want to give a reason, @SergeyA?

Comment: Yes, I have a reason. Most often than not callee site has no idea if an error is critical or not. Even `new` operator you mention has a `nothrow` version. Traditionally this problem has been solved thorough (variously implemented) policies: i.e. `nothrow` version of `new`, `exceptions` call on the stream or anything else. `std::optional` has another way of achieving the same goal - call site can either access the value unconditionally and have exception thrown on errors, or check the result availability and implement recovery strategies. Also, it yields better performance than stack unwinding.

Comment: There is a very simple definition of a (critical) error: If I can't deliver what I promised. So, if I promise to add two numbers, failure to do that is an error. If I promise to do my best adding two numbers, failure to do that is not an error. These guarantees are given by the callee and they are asserted by the callee, too. Whether failure to add two numbers is considered critical by the caller is irrelevant.

Comment: You are engaging in tautology, and basically saying that you need to throw exceptions if you need to throw exceptions, jumping a couple of hops between. Sane API usually is in no position to make a decision of a hard promise. Like I said before, even `new` (when taken as a family of operators) doesn't make this promise. If you take a more general view from C++, you will find that this idea of policy based exception can be seen in many places - i.e. floating point can generate FPE or not based on your settings.

Comment: I don't seem to make myself clear to you. You said, that the callee can't decide whether an error is critical or not. All I said is that how to treat an error follows from the interface definition. For the implementation behind that interface to be correct, it must uphold these guarantees. If it didn't, it wouldn't even be internally consistent. The reason I mentioned that is to show that your claim "callee site has no idea if an error is critical" is misleading and that there are error handling decisions that can and must be made by the callee.

Comment: It is tautology again. Callee is the one defining interface, and it is very rarely in position to make a good decision regarding the interface guarantees in case of errors. Yes, there are some clear cut cases, but most often they would be simple bugs (like `at` throws exception when going out of bounds, but an attempt to do this is a bug). So one might say than an exception is a way to treat states which could only be entered as a result of application bugs, but this is a far shot from your 'use exception by default'.

Comment: @SergeyA why does using `at()` with an index out of range have to be a bug?  It's well defined behaviour, and if someone's smoked something strong enough where it makes sense in a specific situation to let it throw rather than test the size themselves then it's a bug to do anything different.  That said; this is exactly why opinion based questions are off topic.

Comment: @UKMonkey, what I meant to say, physically accessing out-of-bounds index on an array is a bug (because it is undefined behavior). Because of that, `at()` is correct to throw an exception when it detects such access. An error-returning interface makes no sense in this case. In contrast, opening file file when the file is not present might be a bug or not, but average file opening API has no chance of knowing. And way more API I deal with on day-to-day basis are of a latter category. This is what all my comments were about, and I am basically disputing 'by default' statement.